# Why am I getting an 404 when testing views in django?

Tags: python, django

I am writing a test class to test my registration view. I have tested the `get` method but the `post` seems to give an error. Kindly help me out:

Here is my **tests.py**:

```
class ViewsTest(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.client = Client()

    def test_register(self):
        url = reverse('register')
        response = self.client.get(url)
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
        response = self.client.post('/',
                                    {
                                        'first_name': 'john',
                                        'last_name': 'doe',
                                        'email': 'johndoe@gmail.com',
                                        'password': 'johndoe'
                                    })
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 302)
```

Here is my **urls.py**:

```
url(r'^register/', views.register, name='register'),
```

Here is my **views.py**:

```
def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user_form = CustomUserCreationForm(data=request.POST)
        if user_form.is_valid():
            ob = CustomUserCreationForm.register(user_form)
            if ob.is_active is False and ob.is_staff is False:
                return render(request, 'todoapp/waiting.html')
            else:
                return render(request, 'todoapp/admin_success.html')
        else:
            return render(request, 'todoapp/register.html', {'errors': user_form.errors})
    return render(request, 'todoapp/register.html', {'form': CustomUserCreationForm()})
```

Here is the **error** I am getting:

```
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 302)
AssertionError: 404 != 302
```

Comment: Are you sure you're actually intending to send the post request to / and not the reverse('register') URL? If so replace '/' with `url`. Beyond that, to debug further, I'd probably look to log the 404 response body to see if Django's detailed debug response contains anything useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you should pass `url` instead of '/' client is not able to find the url hence returning 404

```
response = self.client.post(url,
                                    {
                                        'first_name': 'john',
                                        'last_name': 'doe',
                                        'email': 'johndoe@gmail.com',
                                        'password': 'johndoe'
                                    })
```

Comment: you're right. Its working now and also `302` is for redirect and `200` essentially means OK and since I am using `render` I used status code as `200`. So its working now. Thanks a lot.